Julia - Find argmin of function over values of an array
I have a function f and an array A with values, I want to calculate argmin(f) regarding the values in the array.
For example:
f(x,y)=2x^2-y^2

A=[1 2; 3 4]

My intuitive approach was to try
argmin(f,A)

But I get the error message:
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching (::var"#f#6")(::Int64)

I would like to get the index of the row in A for which f is minimal.
I know I could calculate the argmin with for-loops, but is there a more elegant/efficient way that uses the argmin directly?

Which version of Julia do you use?

I am using Julia v1.10


I would like to get the index of the row in A for which f is minimal.

Method argmin(f, X) gives value xmin from collection X for which f is minimal. To find index of xmin in collection X use findmin(f, X).
So, for your example the solution would be
julia> f(x, y) = 2*x^2 - y^2

julia> A = [1 2; 3 4]

julia> g(x) = f(x[1], x[2])  # or, more general g(x) = f(x...)

julia> minvalue, minindex = findmin(g, eachrow(A))
# Avoiding defintion of g:  findmin(row -> f(row...), eachrow(A))
(-2, 1)

julia> A[minindex, :]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2

The method error you get is caused by iteration behavior over Matrix. Function argmin iterates over a collection in default manner, for Matrix it is iteration over its elements. On other hand, eachrow(A) gives an iterator over Matrix's rows.
Compare
julia> for x in A
           println(x)
       end
1
3
2
4

julia> for x in eachrow(A)
           println(x)
       end
[1, 2]
[3, 4]

So, in your case argmin(f, A) iterates over elements of A, and call f(element_of_A), but there is no method for f which takes one argument. That's why g function is needed.

Hello, thank you for your answer! Is there a way to avoid to explicitly define g(x)? While your method works for my example, i am looking for a way to do that more general. For example if i have a function that depends on n variables. Or i have multiple functions while one depends on 6 different variables and the other depends on 9, or. Is there a way to avoid writing g(x)=f(x[1],...,x[n])

@Moritz, yes. The syntax g(x) = f(x[1], x[2]) is generalized like this g(x) = f(x...) for f(x1), f(x1, x2), f(x1, x2, x3) and so on. See splat operator for this. To omit definition of g, use anonymous function, e.g. findmin(row -> f(row...), eachrow(A)).

There are some more possibilities also, you can use the convenience function splat, like this: findmin(splat(f), eachrow(A)), or a generator, like this: findmin(f(row...) for row in eachrow(A)).  Note that splatting Arrays has a performance penalty, since the number of elements is not known at compile time.

@StepanZakharov, thank you, i didnt knew about the splat operator, it was exactly what i was looking for.

@DNF thank you, this is interesting! Could you elaborate on the performance penalty or hint me a source where i can read about that?

@Moritz f(x...) takes each element in x as an input argument to f. Which version/method of f that is called depends on the number of elements in x. If the compiler can tell the length of x beforehand, from the type of x alone, then it knows which method of f to call. If not, the correct method must be selected at run-time, incurring a significant cost. The Array type tag does not carry information about its own size, only an actual instance will hold that info. If x is a fixed-length tuple or StaticArray, you can tell, and the correct call is resolved at compile time.

argmin(f,A) will iterate over each element of A to find the one that gives the smalles function output, it will not iterate over the rows of A. In other words it will start by calling f(A[1]), and A[1] is 1, so it's calling f(1). But the function f takes two arguments, not one, and will therefore fail.
You can iterate over the rows of A using the eachrow iterator, for example like this:
julia> findmin(f(row[1], row[2]) for row in eachrow(A))
(-2, 1)

The first output is the value, the second is the index into the row iterator. The function argmax will actually also work here, but I recommend findmin, since argmin generally returns the input value that minimizes the call, not the minimum index. Actually, I find the behaviour of argmin/argmax very hard to understand and predict, and there has been some debate about its behaviour in the Julia community.
BTW, since Julia Arrays are column major, it is generally recommended to not read data row-wise from them, but column-wise. If you can decide the layout for yourself, I would change the orientation of the input matrix, and use eachcol instead of eachrow.

Hello, thank you for your answer, that was very helpful! This works fine for my example, however if i have a function that depends on n variables, or multiple functions with one depending on n while the other depends on n-1 variables. Is there a way to find a more general way/make it directly dependent on the dimension of my Matrix?
